# Splash screen not showing up in iOS 9 Safari

Tags: ios, safari, ios9, homescreen

I'm working on a website for a client and noticed that when I pin the website to the homescreen on a device using iOS 9, the splash screen isn't showing up anymore.

This particular test was against the iPhone 6+/6s+. If I switch to iOS 8.4 in the iOS Simulator, however, it does show the splash screen as expected.

Any ideas what might have changed? I tried searching on both Google and here, but I haven't come across anything regarding this issue.

I've included my code below.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <title>iOS Splash Screen Test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="iOS Splash Screen Test" />

    <!-- iOS: Safari -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="iOS Splash" />

    <!-- iPhone 6+/6s+ -->
    <link href="http://placehold.it/180x180.png" sizes="180x180" rel="apple-touch-icon" />

    <link href="http://placehold.it/1242x2148.png" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />

    <link href="http://placehold.it/1182x2208.png" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
</head>

<body>
    Placeholder text.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a known issue with iOS9: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23924.

Comment: I noticed it works now (iOS 11.2 - maybe it worked earlier, saw it today).